# Why is the previous object array entry being overwritten?

Tags: java

**NOTE: For this assignment, I'm forbidden from using ArrayList, HashMap or any other data structures within the Java API or from 3rd party libraries.** So please don't tell me to use any of these, I want to but I can't.

I'm meant to use a template given by them to do each assignment stage/section. But I've decided to just do it separately first. The problem only begin after I added the code into their given template.

The problem:

- cartItems[0] is overwriting cartItems[1] in addItems() of ShoppingCart.java, making the equals() function returning true regardless. Thus, "SHOPPING CART ALREADY EXISTS" will always be printed.

code in question (ShoppingCart.java)

```
 public void addItems(ItemToPurchase item) {
    boolean result = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++){
        if (numOfItem == 0){
            result = true;
        }else if(numOfItem >= 1){
            if (cartItems[i].getName().equals(item.getName())) {
                System.out.println("SHOPPING CART ALREADY EXISTS.");
                result = false;
            }
            if (!(cartItems[i].getName().equals(item.getName()))) {
                result = true;
            }
        }

        if (i > CAPACITY){
            System.out.println("SHOPPING CART IS FULL.");
        }
    }
    if(result == true){
        cartItems[numOfItem] = item;
    }
    numOfItem++;
}
```

ShoppingCartManager.java

```
public static void stage2(ShoppingCart cart, ItemToPurchase item){
    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter the customer name:");
    String customerName = scnr.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter the current date:");
    String currentDate = scnr.nextLine();

    cart.setCustomerName(customerName);
    cart.setDate(currentDate);

    cart.printTotal();

    for(int i = 0; i <= 1; i++){
        System.out.println("Enter the item name:");
        String itemName = scnr.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter the item price:");
        int itemPrice = scnr.nextInt();
        scnr.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter the item quantity:");
        int itemQuantity = scnr.nextInt();
        scnr.nextLine();
        item.setName(itemName);
        item.setPrice(itemPrice);
        item.setQuantity(itemQuantity);

        item = new ItemToPurchase(itemName, itemPrice, itemQuantity);
        cart.addItems(item);
    }

    cart.printTotal();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
        ItemToPurchase item = new ItemToPurchase();
        ShoppingCart cart = new ShoppingCart();
        VIPShoppingCart vipCart = new VIPShoppingCart();
        stage2(cart, item);
    }
}
```

Expected results on stage 2 IF not matching names:

```
Enter the customer name:
INSERT NAME HERE
Enter the current date:
INSERT DATE HERE

INSERT NAME HERE - DATE HERE
SHOPPING CART IS EMPTY.

Enter the item name:
Chocolate Chips
Enter the item price:
5
Enter the item quantity:
3

Enter the item name:
Steak
Enter the item price:
3
Enter the item quantity:
2

INSERT NAME HERE - DATE HERE
Number of Items: 5
Chocolate Chips 3 @ $5 = $15
Steak 2 @ $3 = $6
Total: $21
```

Expected results on stage 2 IF matching names:

```
Enter the customer name:
INSERT NAME HERE
Enter the current date:
DATE HERE

INSERT NAME HERE - DATE HERE
SHOPPING CART IS EMPTY.

Enter the item name:
Chocolate Chips
Enter the item price:
5
Enter the item quantity:
3

Enter the item name:
Chocolate Chips
Enter the item price:
3
Enter the item quantity:
2

SHOPPING CART ALREADY EXISTS.
INSERT NAME HERE - DATE HERE
Number of Items: 3
Chocolate Chips 3 @ $5 = $15
Total: $15
```

Actual results:

```
Enter the customer name:
INSERT NAME HERE
Enter the current date:
DATE HERE

INSERT NAME HERE - DATE HERE
SHOPPING CART IS EMPTY.

Enter the item name:
Chocolate Chips
Enter the item price:
5
Enter the item quantity:
3

Enter the item name:
Steak
Enter the item price:
3
Enter the item quantity:
2

SHOPPING CART ALREADY EXISTS.
INSERT NAME HERE - DATE HERE
Number of Items: 2
Steak 2 @ $3 = $6
Total: $6
```

Thanks.

edit: updated expected results to be clearer.

edit2: had to remove full code since the assignment is still up.

Comment: Please include the code as formatted text in your question.

Comment: Not only include your code, but also leave out the parts not relevant to the problem. Try and follow these guidelines https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: included code in question. Deleted all parts irrelevant to my question.

Comment: Please don't add things like "solved" to the title. You mark a question as solved by accepting an answer, or if there is no suitable answer to accept, posting your own answer and accepting that after the timeout.

Comment: Sorry, will take note of that next time, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existing code has several issues in the `for` loop:

- there's no need to compare `i` to `CAPACITY` in the loop, this decision can be made on current value of `numOfItems`
- there is typo in the `for` loop condition: `...; i < 1; ...` - current value `numOfItem` should be used as a limit
- when checking if an item exist in the cart, the code should return as soon as the item is found.

Upon resolving the mentioned issues, the following code should work:

```java
public void addItems(ItemToPurchase item) {
    if (numOfItem == CAPACITY) {
        System.out.println("SHOPPING CART IS FULL.");
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < numOfItem; i++) {
        if (cartItems[i].getName().equals(item.getName())) {
            System.out.println("SHOPPING CART ITEM ALREADY EXISTS.");
            return;
        }
    }
    // capacity is available, and the item is not found in the array
    cartItems[numOfItem++] = item;
}
```

---

[Online demo](https://ideone.com/uDeDFj):

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
 
/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    private static final int CAPACITY = 2;
 
    private static ItemToPurchase[] cartItems = new ItemToPurchase[CAPACITY];
 
    private static int numOfItem;
 
    public static void addItems(ItemToPurchase item) {
        if (numOfItem == CAPACITY) {
            System.out.println("SHOPPING CART IS FULL.");
            return;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < numOfItem; i++) {
            if (cartItems[i].getName().equals(item.getName())) {
                System.out.println("SHOPPING CART ITEM ALREADY EXISTS.");
                return;
            }
        }
        // capacity is available, and the item is not found in the array
        cartItems[numOfItem++] = item;
    }
 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Cart: " + numOfItem + "; items: " + Arrays.toString(cartItems));
        addItems(new ItemToPurchase("Chocolate Chips", 5, 3));
        System.out.println("Added 1, cart: " + numOfItem + "; items: " + Arrays.toString(cartItems));
 
        addItems(new ItemToPurchase("Chocolate Chips", 2, 4));
        System.out.println("Adding failed, cart: " + numOfItem + "; items: " + Arrays.toString(cartItems));
 
        addItems(new ItemToPurchase("Strawberry Jam", 2, 3));
        System.out.println("Added 2, cart: " + numOfItem + "; items: " + Arrays.toString(cartItems));
 
        addItems(new ItemToPurchase("Orange Juice", 2, 5));
        System.out.println("Adding failed, cart: " + numOfItem + "; items: " + Arrays.toString(cartItems));
    }
}
```

```java
class ItemToPurchase {
    private final String name;
    private final int quantity;
    private final int price;
 
    public ItemToPurchase(String name, int quantity, int price) {
        this.name = name;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.price = price;
    }
 
    public String getName() { return name; }
    public int getQuantity() { return quantity; }
    public int getPrice() { return price; }
 
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ItemToPurchase{" +
                "name='" + getName() + '\'' +
                ", quantity=" + getQuantity() +
                ", price=" + getPrice() +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Cart: 0; items: [null, null]
Added 1, cart: 1; items: [ItemToPurchase{name='Chocolate Chips', quantity=5, price=3}, null]
SHOPPING CART ITEM ALREADY EXISTS.
Adding failed, cart: 1; items: [ItemToPurchase{name='Chocolate Chips', quantity=5, price=3}, null]
Added 2, cart: 2; items: [ItemToPurchase{name='Chocolate Chips', quantity=5, price=3}, ItemToPurchase{name='Strawberry Jam', quantity=2, price=3}]
SHOPPING CART IS FULL.
Adding failed, cart: 2; items: [ItemToPurchase{name='Chocolate Chips', quantity=5, price=3}, ItemToPurchase{name='Strawberry Jam', quantity=2, price=3}]
```

Comment: It did not, unfortunately. I tried putting Strawberry Jam and Chocolate Chips instead, it still outputs that item exists regardless. https://imgur.com/a/mNdhgwe

Comment: It does, please check the [online demo](https://ideone.com/uDeDFj)

Comment: as I said, I tried, and it did not work. When I replaced the snippet of my code to yours and tested, the results I've obtained is what I got in the imgur link. I'm not sure if it'll help, but I've tried your code separately in a file without the given ShoppingCartManager template, and it works. My messy code before also works if I do not put it in the given template. When I do do so however, it starts to overwrite my previous object entries. That is my issue. If you need it, I can upload the empty given ShoppingCartManager template into GitHub for comparison. (edit: uploaded it anyway.)

Comment: There is a bug in `stage2` method [lines 41-43](https://github.com/ZWLam-alt/ShoppingCart/blob/main/ShoppingCartManager.java#L41-L43): first you set the newly entered values to _existing_ item (thus its fields are modified and you should see it if you print cart contents), and then you create a new item with the same new values and try to add it.  Therefore you get "item already exists" error.  It seems these lines have to be removed, though the entire logic is a bit too messy  and something else might get broken then.

Comment: Also, I do not see that the fix I suggested is applied to the code on Git.

Comment: I'll double check my entire code next time, I'm really sorry. Thank you so much, I've removed line 41-43 and had it working!